# What is Lambda definability?

Tags: functional-programming, lambda-calculus

While I was reading about lambda calculus, came across the word **Lambda definability**. Can someone please explain what that is as I couldn't find any good resources on that.

Thanks

Comment: Can you give a quotation and a source?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the [Church-Turing](http://www.alanturing.net/turing_archive/pages/reference%20articles/The%20Turing-Church%20Thesis.html) thesis, where lambda-definable functions (from Church) are those that give us ["effectively computable"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computable_function) functions. Turing showed that programs implementable on a Turing machine are equivalent to lambda-definable functions.

Answer (score 4):

More generally, there is a line of research seeking to characterize "lambda definability" over a broad class of languages. "lambda definability" itself is typically relative to a semantics of a language given in terms of sets. For a type `T` in our language, write `|T|` for its interpretation as a set. Now, take an element of `|T|` -- call it `e`. We want to know if there is a term in our language -- call it `x : T` (x of type T), such that |x| is `e`. If there is such a term, then we say that `t` is lambda-definable.

Now, in our perfect world, when we interpret a language into sets, we would like to say that the sets associated with each type are precisely those that contain the lambda-definable elements of that type and *only* the lambda-definable elements (completeness). It would also be nice, perhaps to say that we can provide an algorithm to *determine* if a claimed element of a set has an associated lambda term (decidability).

Now, often we don't just model into sets, but into other funny mathematical constructions. And we don't model just from the lambda calculus, but from other related systems such as Plotkin's PCF or the like. But the property under study is typically still called "lambda-definability".

After decades of research there are still many open problems and questions in this regard -- while certain lower-order terms have been shown to have decidable lambda-definability (the classic results involve terms up to second-order), many terms do not yield so easily. This paper ("The Undecidability of lambda-Definability" by Ralph Loader) gives an important such undecidability result and characterizes some consequences: http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.36.6860